# insert annotation to a word document by using POI or DOCX4J

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi, docx4j, python-docx

I'd like to insert some annotations into work documents by using Java or Python. I tried POI, DOCX4J and python-docx. But unfortunately until now I didn't figure out how to use them to generate annotation in a word document.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For docx4j, please see [docx4j/samples/CommentsSample.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/CommentsSample.java)